# (Laravel/PHP) SQL Query that selects all orders from table that matches product_id and variation_id in array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

Im trying to build a SQL Query that will select all orders from a table that matches options that i defined.

Databse i use: Mysql
Language: PHP

Basicly i have a array that looks like this.

```
[
 [
   "user_id" => 1,
   "product_id" => 5548, 
   "variation_id" => 14
 ], 
 [
   "user_id" => 1, 
   "product_id" => 5548, 
   "variation_id" => 15
 ],
 [
   "user_id" => 1, 
   "product_id" => 4422, 
   "variation_id" => 4
 ]
]
```

This means that the user(id: 1) has one product with the "id" of 5548, and then he also has 2 variations of that product that are "id" 14 and 15. You can also see that the same user owns the product(id:4422) that has variation(id:4).

I then have a "order_lines" table that looks like this

```
order_lines
+----+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | uid | user_id | product_id  |  variation_id |
+----+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| 1  |  1  |     1   |     5548    |       14      |
+----+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| 2  |  2  |     1   |     5548    |       15      |
+----+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| 3  |  3  |     1   |     4422    |        4      |
+----+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| .  |  .  |     .   |     ....    |       ..      |
+----+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
```

I now need a SQL Query that selects all the rows where there is a match between the user_id, product_id and variation_id that are defined in the array.

The output should contain all rows that meet these conditions.

I hope someone can pin me in the right direction.

I'm building in Laravel if you got the query builder just at your hand. Else i very much appreciate an SQL Query.

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

if I am getting you right, below code will help you, using just Core PHP

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    $user_id = $arr['user_id'];
    $prodct_id = $arr['prodct_id'];
    $variation_id = $arr['variation_id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM order_lines WHERE user_id = $userId AND product_id = $productId AND variation_id = $variationId";
    $queryResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $yourCollection[] = $queryResult;
}
    print_r($yourCollection);
```

Comment: Not efficient, would take too many hits on the database, doesn't sound great for a live website when this loop would run umteen times

Comment: @MehravishTemkar, may be you are right, but I think this is what he is asking for. anyways, he will read your comment :)

Comment: @VishalParkash Just as Mehravish Temkar pointed out, im actually looking for a bit more efficient way. Thank you for the input tho!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to use Laravel Query Builder, below code will help you to get results for multiple users based on product and variation.

```
$qb_order_lines = DB::table('order_lines');

$where_condition = [
    ['user_id' => '', 'product_id' => '', 'variation_id' => ''],
];

foreach ($where_condition as $condition) {
    $qb_order_lines->orWhere(function($query) use ($condition) {
        $query->where('user_id', $condition['user_id'])
                ->where('product_id', $condition['product_id'])
                ->where('variation_id', $condition['variation_id']);
    });
}
$obj_result = $qb_order_lines->get();
```

If you want to get it for only one user, use below code

```
$obj_result = DB::table('order_lines')
        ->where('user_id', $condition['user_id'])
        ->where('product_id', $condition['product_id'])
        ->where('variation_id', $condition['variation_id'])
        ->get();
```

You can modify the above query builders based on your requirements like select fields or group by.

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interesting.

My problem was that i needed to count of many matches that were between my array and my database.

Instead of selecting and outputting. I eneded up using sql count() function in a query, that did the job.

Comment: It would make this answer considerably better if you supplied the actual code which you used to solve your problem.